# Exam class: figure not showing up?

Tags: exam, includegraphics

I have created a `.pdf` image using `tikz` in a separate, `standalone` class document, then converted it independently to a `.png` file and saved it in the same folder as my `exam` class document. I can preview it separately just fine, so I know the original `.pdf` was compiled correctly. However, upon compilation of the `exam` class file, a blank image is showing. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    answers
    ]{exam}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Hello
        
        \ifprintanswers
        \begin{minipage}[h!]{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.3\textheight,natwidth=1,natheight=1]{./circuito_C.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Il circuito \(C\).}
            \label{fig:circuito_C}
        \end{minipage}
        \fi
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

When I load `graphicx` with the `demo` option, a black square of the correct size shows in place of the image. What's wrong?

Comment: That‘s most likely by intention. When you design the layout of a document, say a newspaper, the images might not be available at that time. So Layouters posted said placeholder. When you remove the demo option, it will look for the real image and complain, if it‘s missing. // See ch. 4.1 in the manual https://ctan.joethei.xyz/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf

Comment: Is ;your image file in the same directory as the .tex file?  If it is in the parent directory, you should use `../` (two dots).  IIRC, `./foo` is used if foo is a subdirectory.

Comment: See also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me, options `natwidth` and `nathweight` removed and using the `graphicx` option for example image:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Hello
        
        \ifprintanswers
        \begin{minipage}[h!]{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{Il circuito \(C\).}
            \label{fig:circuito_C}
        \end{minipage}
        \fi
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]